# How to keep mat-datepicker calender open, even after selecting a date from calendar?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2, angular5

I want to keep `mat-datepicker` open in a particular div. I used `opened=true` property but it gets closed after selecting a date.

Comment: if you would provide an example on stackblitz that might help

Comment: You can check this.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysspzm?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html

Comment: did you find a solution that solves your problem?

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

Add this to your `input`

```
(click)="_openCalendar(picker)"
#keepOpen
```

This to your `mat-datepicker`

```
(closed)="_openCalendar(picker)"
```

And this to your typescript:

```
@ViewChild('keepOpen') _input: ElementRef;

_openCalendar(picker: MatDatepicker<Date>) {
  picker.open();
}
```

Don't forget to import `ViewChild` and `ElementRef`

That's my working sample on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysspzm-ckkrbd)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it is keeping calender open :) but when I scroll my page , calender is not fixed in particular DIV , it is getting up and down.Can we fix it in particular div like input box and other things are fixed?

Comment: again...if you would provide an example on stackblitz that might make it easier for anybody to help

Comment: i think you are looking for `display: fix` instead of `block` (in the css). That will prevent the calendar to stay in view.

Comment: Does this work? In my case, when I select a date, the calendar closes and then open so it looks weird.

Answer (score -1):

Use closed event in Datepicker and make it force to open.
Working Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysspzm-ge2r2y