# How to keep opened mat-datepicker after choosing date?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I am looking for a solution that keeps open the Angular Material Datepicker or mat-datepicker after choosing date.

I had followed this solution, the only problem with solution is every time I choose date it closes and reopens with animation. My every try failed to stop that animation.

[How to keep mat-datepicker calender open, even after selecting a date from calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589538/how-to-keep-mat-datepicker-calender-open-even-after-selecting-a-date-from-calen)

Below is the code of mat datepicker

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" aria-owns="mat-datepicker-0" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker #picker class="d-block"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add below code to disable animation as per https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4227#issuecomment-348148642

```
constructor( private overlayContainer:OverlayContainer, private renderer:Renderer2 ) {

    const disableAnimations:boolean = true;

    // get overlay container to set property that disables animations
    const overlayContainerElement:HTMLElement = this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement();

    // angular animations renderer hooks up the logic to disable animations into setProperty
    this.renderer.setProperty( overlayContainerElement, "@.disabled", disableAnimations);
}
```

and https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xq2upq working code